# Custom Wordpress search and query url

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create a custom search page in a Wordpress website. I read a few tutorials on Google and I have almost finished with it.

My theme uses the `index.php` page for the search results. So, I duplicated it, rename it to `searchpage.php`, made it a template and created a page with this template in Wordpress admin.

Then, I changed the action on the Search form to use the new page of `/search`.

If I manually try the `/search/test/` it works. If I use the widget it redirect to `/search/?s=test` and returns a 404 page.

Is there any way to make both works or prevent the widget to use the second?

Also, the `/search/test` still uses the `index.php` layout instead of the `searchpage.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to overwrite index.php as the default search results page you'll need to name your file search.php

Comment: I did it. Thank you. The problem of not calling the new template has solved. However, I still cannot solve the issue of the query.

Comment: If you remove the action of the search form to use /search, it should properly route your ?s= query to the new search results page.

Comment: I have also another problem. I will open a new question for it. Thank you for this. If I change the action back to "/", it works in both ways.